# When is a Javascript constructor function executed when using CommonJS modularity through node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

In a CommonJS implementation of a module through Node, I have this infantModule.js:

filename: **infantModule.js**

```
var infant = function(gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
    //technically, when passed though this line, I'm born!
};

var infantInstance = new infant('female');

module.exports = infantInstance;
```

My question is:

When is this module's constructor function really executed, considering other module consuming this infantModule, such as:

filename: **index.js** -- entry point of the application

```
var infantPerson = require('./infantModule');
// is it "born" at this line? (1st time it is "required")

console.log(infantPerson);
// or is it "born" at this line? (1st time it is referenced)
```

Since my infantModule exposes a ready-made instantiated object, all other future requires of this module, by any other modules besides the index.js entry point, will reference this same object, that behaves like a shared instance in the application, is it correct to put it that way?

If there's an additional line of code in index.js at the bottom, such as:

```
infantInstance.gender = 'male';
```

Any other module in my application besides index.js, that require infantModule at a future point in time, will get the object with the gender property changed, is it the correct assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` returns a normal object.  Nothing magical happens when you access that object.

Specifically, the first time you call `require()`, Node will execute the entire contents of the required file, and will then return the value of its `module.exports` property.